# PDF Editor that Can Save Annotation and Comments for Other Platforms and Viewers

Tags: pdf, crossplatform, annotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I highlight PDFs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-pdfs)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I collaborate with others on academic papers and they frequently send PDF versions of the document we are working on with comments and annotations to me. In this case they placed comments using a PDF editing software on Mac. I can view their comments using *Okular* -- but when I insert any comment or annotations using *Okular* on the PDF they are not able to see it.

To clarify, the PDF editing software itself does not have to be cross platform, as long as the result can be saved and viewed on other platforms. How can I add comments and annotations to PDF file so they are viewable on other platforms and popular PDF viewers. I am looking for a reliable solution. Missing annotations can result in serious miscommunication when collaborating with others remotely.

ps: this is not a duplicate of [this post on viewing comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86015/viewing-pdf-comments) since I am looking for a solution that let me reliably annotate and comment on PDF files and email them to others for viewing.

Comment: @Anwar: No, in my case I need a crossplatform solution. As I said in the question, Okular is not the answer -- unfortunately.

Comment: Why you need croos platform if the solution can work. You can comments and highlight pdfs using the solutions there. Specifically, X-PDF-Changer. So, the problem is solved. IMO

Comment: ok you are right, I dont need the tool itself to be cross platform. So you are suggesting X-PDF-Changer?