# How to view pdf with markup

Tags: 20.04, pdf, evince, okular

I'm trying to view my advisor's comments on a PDF of a manuscript. He's made comments using Adobe software in the past, and I've been able to use evince or okular to view them. Now neither works, and I'm kind of at a loss for what to do. Is there a way to view PDF comments on Ubuntu 20.04?

I'm happy to provide any supporting information, but other than that I'm on 20.04 and have up-to-date `apt install`ed versions of Okular and Evince I don't know what else to say. Note also that [this response](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86015/viewing-pdf-comments) does not actually resolve my issue, which is with viewing *someone else's* comments, not making comments someone else can read.

Comment: are you getting any error messages when you view the file in evince?  And both firefox and chromium can open pdf - not sure if the comments would show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try your luck with [Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/), which is considered as one of the best free (not open-source) PDF editors for highlighting, annotating and adding/reading comments on PDF files.

To install it, download the .deb package *64 bit - For CentOS/RedHat 7.x, Ubuntu 16.x - 20.x* from [here](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/) and save it (e.g. in your `~/Downloads`).

Then open your terminal and run:

```
sudo apt install ~/Downloads/master-pdf-editor-5.6.80-qt5.x86_64.deb
```

If you haven't downloaded the package in `~/Downloads`, change `~/Downloads` to your actual download path in the above command.

Comment: Actually this seems to have similar issues to evince/firefox; the PDF comment function allows someone to place a caret somewhere, indicating that text they type into a text box should be inserted there. For whatever reason, this text appears if I hold my mouse over the caret for a bit (kind of like a tooltip), but like a tooltip it goes away if I move my mouse at all. Unlike a highlighted comment I cannot click on the caret and see the text in the objects box to the right.